# save image from Scroll view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

help please. I have this code that shows me images in scrollview.:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    NSArray *imgNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"ip1.jpg", @"ip2.jpg", @"ip3.jpg", @"ip4.jpg", @"ip5.jpg", @"ip6.jpg", @"ip7.jpg", @"ip8.jpg", @"ip9.jpg", @"ip10.jpg",@"ip11.jpg",@"ip12.jpg",@"ip13.jpg",@"ip14.jpg",@"ip15.jpg",@"ip16.jpg",@"ip17.jpg",@"ip18.jpg",@"ip19.jpg",@"ip20.jpg",@"ip21.jpg", nil];


    // Setup the array of UIImageViews
    NSMutableArray *imgArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    UIImageView *tempImageView;
    for(NSString *name in imgNames) {
        tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        tempImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        tempImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:name];
        [imgArray addObject:tempImageView];

    }
 CGSize pageSize = scrollViewBack.frame.size; // scrollView is an IBOutlet for our UIScrollView
    NSUInteger page = 0;
    for(UIView *view in imgArray) {
        [scrollViewBack addSubview:view];

        // This is the important line
        view.frame = CGRectMake(pageSize.width * page++ + 40, 0, pageSize.width - 80,  pageSize.height);
 }   



    scrollViewBack.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pageSize.width * [imgArray count], pageSize.height);

}
```

Now, I want a UILabel, that will show me, Image name, when I will scroll. Help me please, I can't implement that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why can't?? Only your are going to code for yourself. I fear that if anyone is going to code for you.

Comment: @Till if you get that stuff please do share with me. My demands are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second `for` loop you can acces to the indexes of the objects of `imgArray` and `imgNames`, so try this:

```
int idx = [imgArray indexOfObject:view];
NSString *strName = [imgNames objectAtIndex:idx];
//create the label
label.text=strName;
//add the label in the scrollView
```

If you want to show the label just when the new image is showed, keep the two arrays as iVars and use [UIPageControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to track in wich page of the scrollview you are. ([Sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)).

Comment: Hey. Thanks. i works, BUT, IF I USE NSLOG TO SHOW IT. I will show me number like "1124580". I also Implemented Page Control, it works, but if i want to show with NSlog only current page number, it also show me "1141212" Help me please.

Comment: Probably you're formatting the string in the wrong way. It should looks like `label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",name];`. Or please show how you're setting the string.

Answer (score 1):

In your loop you could do something like this. Read the apple docs. Search google for how to make a label. Its not hard to learn this stuff if you just try.

```
for(NSString *name in imgNames) {
    // ....

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:WHEREYOUWANTIT];
    [label setText:name];
}
```